# Spring-social getting access_token

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social

Hi 2 all guys i make all like in tutorial. But i have stopped on getting access_Token. So this is my code that redirect to facebook.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void process(/*
                     * @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult
                     * result Model model,
                     */HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory("240362226072898", "657532dea6d091ab44a56668c47cca15");
    OAuth2Operations oauthOperations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
    OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters("http://localhost:8080/shop/facebook");
    String authorizeUrl = oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl(GrantType.IMPLICIT_GRANT, params);

    try {
        response.sendRedirect(authorizeUrl);
        LOG.error("ALL WORKING FINE>>>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Errorrrrr" + e);
    }
```

After that in other controller. which mapped on /facebook i recieve an URL but there i can not find any parametrs cause at the end of the url i see #. like

```
http://localhost:8080/shop/facebook#access_token=.......&expires_in=6277
```

if i cut "#" and paste "?" there everything will be fine

so this is my controller where i recieve this url.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/facebook")
public class FacebookController {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FacebookController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public void getAuthorisation(@RequestParam String access_token, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {

        LOG.error("Access token"+access_token);
/*      LOG.error(request.getAttribute("access_token"));
        LOG.error(request.getParameter("access_token"));
*/      
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he is looking for how to access the access_token in the `FacebookController`.

Comment: Yeah exactly! cause i can not to retrieve access_token from such URL with "#". It do not see access_token as a parametr. I want to ask is there problem in controllers or maybe some configs

Comment: Hashes don't get sent to server-side as parameters, as they are client-side (browser) only. Use JavaScript to extract that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the access token from the [URI fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) using Javascript.

See the documentation for [client side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/):

> If the user chooses to authorize your application, the user will be
>   redirected to:
>
> YOUR_REDIRECT_URI#access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN&expires_in=NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_UNTIL_TOKEN_EXPIRES
>
> Note that unlike the
>   server-side flow, the access token is passed to your redirect_uri in
>   the url fragment and so is only available to your application through
>   Javascript.

Comment: Maybe you should consider server side flow.

Comment: ? i can't recieve anything after #. #-troll me even in JAVA =(... I heart about @FacebookAccesToken annotation. Anybody heart about it?

Comment: yes i also heard about it..but facing same prob like u lgor.. :( i m searing for same..but still didn't get any server side code..any help plz?